# Should I be using a Mac for developing in Salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I know this will not have a clearcut answer, but I have been developing on the force.com platform for a few years now.  It seems everyone at Dream force is on a mac-book.  Seems like its 7 or 8 to 1 mac to windows.  This could be much larger than just Salesfroce development, and could be just a general development question, but I am just wondering as I develop full time in force.com.

I'm just looking for some pros and cons and is there a clear cut reason to make the switch from windows to mac

Comment: Have to close this as it's only going to create a lot of discussion which doesn't work here; the success community would be a great place to talk about it though.

In short, what tools you use depends on what you like and what you need. I have always used a Mac for Salesforce development but some tools (like the Excel connector) are Windows only, so it's really down to your specific situation.

Answer (score 6):

Mac vs Windows. The eternal debate (at least, until one collapses as a business). There's a number of features for both camps, but the end result will be that you have to decide for yourself which is the better deal, just as you would for buying a car, a house, etc.

Macs generally have the following benefits:

- Fewer virii are written for Macs, so they are less likely to be infected.
- Macs are generally regarded as "more stable" (e.g. less prone to crashes).
- Macs have software for writing native iOS apps.
- Macs have increasing support in the open software community (e.g. MavensMate).
- Multimedia support is strong, making it easier to build "pretty" websites.

Macs generally have the following drawbacks:

- A Mac generally costs more than a Windows or Linux box with the same hardware features.
- While you can virtualize Windows ala BootCamp, it's still (marginally) slower than just buying Windows hardware.
- Some features of salesforce.com are still Windows-only, such as Classic Mail Merge, CTI Connector, and the Office Toolkit (as far as I can determine; I'd love more info on this). The Data Loader also takes extra effort to run on a Mac.

Windows generally has the following benefits:

- Windows computers are generally less expensive than Macs of the same hardware comparison.
- Windows generally has more commercial software available to it directly as opposed to Mac or Linux.
- It is generally easier to code for Windows devices (e.g. Windows Phone) in Windows.
- The latest versions of Windows are actually incredibly hardened against the ever-increasing virii sent its way, and its almost trivial to secure a Windows system.

Windows generally has the following drawbacks:

- Software tends to be less stable/of lower quality. This doesn't specifically mean open software, just in general; this trend is why Windows 8 has more stringent requirements for its apps, to try and reverse this trend.
- Software tends to be bloated, and leaves little "bits" floating around that bog down the system over time.
- There are new virii emerging daily, so some care has to be exercised with Windows; it still seems easier to infect a Windows device than either a Mac or Linux device. This isn't necessarily because it's "less secure", but rather due to the number of attacks directed at the platform.

In summary, you generally have a choice of more software vs. high quality software, more potential threats vs. less potential threats, and more cost vs. less cost.

Do your research before deciding to ditch Windows to make sure it's really what you want to do. It's cheaper to keep your current hardware than to switch. However, if you're in the market to upgrade anyways (i.e. your hardware needs to be replaced), then cost is less of a factor, and you might find that it's time to make the switch.

I have personally dabbled in many operating systems, including many flavors of Linux, almost all versions of Windows, and in many "other" systems, including Chromebook, MenuetOS, Haiku, and a few others that escape my memory at the moment. My personal Mac experience is limited, mostly because the cost of ownership of a Mac is higher, since I can't just install MacOS on my existing hardware; if I could, I'd probably ditch Windows in a New York minute.

However, that aside, I can say with some confidence that if you don't do your research before jumping, you might not like what's on the other side. It's for this reason that I still do my salesforce.com development in Windows and not on my Chromebook, for example. If Mac has the features you want, and you're in the market to upgrade (and not just trade across the same level), then that might be your own clear cut reason that you are looking for. Otherwise, the decision might not be so obvious, and nobody but you can really answer that question.

I'd be interested in seeing which route you decided to take.

Answer (score 1):

I have personally never developed on a Mac but I did read this very interesting article sometime ago which would explain why we see the folks at SF using Macs.

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/apple/salesforce-dumping-4000-pcs-for-macs/1624

This article suggests that the main reason is security and I would agree.

I know that there are far less malwares, trojans and other hideous things out there for Macs as compared to Windows. I would probably love to develop on a more secure non windows platform. So thats probably one good pro for you on Mac v/s Windows.

Comment: Mac isn't necessarily safer, simply more obscure. See http://gs.statcounter.com/#os-ww-monthly-200807-201307 as an example. MacOS is still under 10% global usage (compared to Microsoft's nearly 80%). This number also plays into another important aspect; software has become more accessible, but there is still far more salesforce.com code that is only accessible for Windows (e.g. CTI Connector doesn't run anywhere but Windows). Cost is also a factor. Show  me a $320 Mac that compares to a Windows box.

Comment: In the end, it comes down to opinion, however. Despite my prior comment, I'd say that Mac has reached a level of accessibility that finally makes it viable for salesforce.com development, so long as you're not working on a new CTI adapter or trying to use the Office Toolkit, etc. A person has to consider the utility of the tools they are buying in terms of features they want vs. what the tool has. As such, this is more of an opinion question than a basis of factual, scientifically provable data. My advice would be to look for the hardware and software that best matches their needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah theres no doubt its a larger trend than the SF community for dev. At my last company macbooks were standard unless you requested a PC.

Now I'm considering making the switch from PC to Mac. I'd like to be able to use x-code and do iphone native app dev. Also I really like the Mavensmate Sublime Text plugin for apex/vf development. I'm not a huge fan of Eclipse. Those reasons and the battery life on the new macbook air are my biggest reasons for wanting to switch.

Answer (score 1):

I use a mac to develop on salesforce everyday.

MavensMate for Sublime Text is 1000% better then using the Force.com IDE

You can check it out here!

https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText

Not to mention that almost all other web development us through unix based servers  and working on a mac makes it much easier to develop locally.